# Position of arrow in tikz flowchart

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, flow-charts

I have the following tickz flow-chart but I want the arrow that goes from the "compute color features" node to stop at the right-hand corner of the "SVM and RF models" node. How do I do this?

[image]

Here is my code.

````
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{figure}[! h]
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\tikzstyle{block1} = [rectangle, draw,fill=gray!20, 
    text width=3cm, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=1cm]
\tikzstyle{block2} = [rectangle, draw,fill=gray!20, 
    text width = 2cm, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height = 2cm]

  
   \node[block1](Input){Input images};
   
  
   \node[block2, below of = Input , xshift = -2cm , yshift = -2cm](glcm){Compute GLCM matrix};
   
   \node[block2, below of = Input , xshift = 2cm , yshift = -2cm](col_features){Compute colour features};
   
  \node[block1, below of = glcm , yshift = -1cm](ext_features){Calculate extracted features};
   
   
   \node[block1, below of = ext_features , yshift = -1cm](average_feature){Calculate average of features};
   
  
  \node[block1, below of = average_feature , yshift = -1cm](models){SVM and RF models};
    
   \node[block2, below of = models , xshift = -2cm , yshift = -2cm](tumor){Image contains a tumor};
   
   \node[block2, below of = models , xshift = 2cm , yshift = -2cm](no_tumor){Image does not contain tumor};

 

    \draw[->](Input)--(glcm);
    \draw[->](glcm)--(ext_features);
    \draw[->](ext_features)--(average_feature);
    \draw[->](average_feature)--(models);
    \draw[->](models)--(tumor);
    \draw[->](models)--(no_tumor);
    \draw[->](Input)--(col_features);
    \draw[->](col_features)--(models);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\caption{Feature extraction flow chart}
\label{fig:feat_ext}
\end{figure}
\end{document}```
````

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Thank you!  Very excited to join the community.

Comment: Please help the community of this site help you and always provide a compilable snippet of code that starts with `\documentclass{...}` and ends with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip see my edit. @JasperHabicht.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SX! You can use an anchor. Ti*k*Z provides a bunch of such anchors for the default node shapes that you can reference to by adding the anchor name to the node name (connected by a dot/fullstop). Most node shapes provide the anchors `north`, `south`, `east` and `west` and combinations thereof, such as `north east`, which would be the anchor you could use here.

See chapter 71 of the [Ti*k*Z/PGF manual](http://ctan.mirror.norbert-ruehl.de/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) where the `shapes` library is discussed which anchors are available for the predefined node shapes.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

    \tikzstyle{block1} = [rectangle, draw,fill=gray!20, 
    text width=3cm, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=1cm]
    \tikzstyle{block2} = [rectangle, draw,fill=gray!20, 
    text width = 2cm, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height = 2cm]
    
    \node[block1](Input){Input images};
    \node[block2, below of = Input, xshift = -2cm, yshift = -2cm](glcm){Compute GLCM matrix};
    \node[block2, below of = Input, xshift = 2cm, yshift = -2cm](col_features){Compute colour features};
    \node[block1, below of = glcm, yshift = -1cm](ext_features){Calculate extracted features};
    \node[block1, below of = ext_features, yshift = -1cm](average_feature){Calculate average of features};
    \node[block1, below of = average_feature, yshift = -1cm](models){SVM and RF models};
    \node[block2, below of = models, xshift = -2cm, yshift = -2cm](tumor){Image contains a tumor};
    \node[block2, below of = models, xshift = 2cm, yshift = -2cm](no_tumor){Image does not contain tumor};

    \draw[->](Input)--(glcm);
    \draw[->](glcm)--(ext_features);
    \draw[->](ext_features)--(average_feature);
    \draw[->](average_feature)--(models);
    \draw[->](models)--(tumor);
    \draw[->](models)--(no_tumor);
    \draw[->](Input)--(col_features);
    \draw[->](col_features)--(models.north east);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I wouldn't use `\tikzstyle` nor `below of` but `below=of` from the `positioning` library. However, for such tree diagrams there is an even more powerful option: `forest`, so you do not even have to worry about such things. Also, a bent arrow may look better in this case.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
 for tree={rectangle, draw,fill=gray!20, 
    text width=3cm,text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=1cm,
    edge={->}}
   [Input images
    [Compute\\ GLCM\\ matrix
     [Calculate extracted features
      [Calculate average of features
       [SVM and RF models,alias=BR
        [Image\\ contains\\ a tumor]
        [Image\\ does not\\ contain tumor]
       ]    
      ] 
     ]  
    ] 
   [Compute\\ colour\\ features,alias=TR]
  ] 
 \draw[->] (TR) to[out=-90,in=45] (BR.north east); 
\end{forest}  
\end{document}
```

[image]